# use text in Yii2 app

Tags: php, html, yii2

I'm trying to echo a message in the title with no luck, here is my title code.

```
<title><?php echo implode(' | ', array_filter([$this->title, Yii::$app->get('systemState')->get('siteTitle')])) ?></title>
```

it should remains exactly the same but show a message before the "systemState".

In current status it shows the title as "flash game | website for flash games".

What i want it to show is " play flash game | website for flash games".

Comment: Do you need the title to be the same on all pages? If you do, you can set it on config/web.php. If you don't, you need to set it on the view file.

Comment: where are you echoing? In the layout or the page-spesific view file?